# What is the impact of adding the same row twice to a cassandra column family?

Tags: schema, cassandra, command-line-interface

I can run this update as many times as I want. I.e. the code doesn't error out if the row 'test' is already present:

```
[default@testdata] update column family my_column_family with
...         column_metadata =
...         [
...         {column_name: test, validation_class: UTF8Type}
... ];
f20046d1-0f89-3c52-b568-c41061e32071
Waiting for schema agreement...
... schemas agree across the cluster
[default@testdata] update column family my_column_family with
...         column_metadata =
...         [
...         {column_name: test, validation_class: UTF8Type}
... ];
299eebb0-3c71-378d-b9cd-972bb35a49e0
Waiting for schema agreement...
... schemas agree across the cluster
```

Also, the update does not remove any existing data in that row.

My question: does adding the same row multiple times have secondary effects I should know about?  I believe an index is dropped on an update unless it is specified again, but I do not worry about this.

I would not expect the updates to be run at a high rate. Possibly every day or so, but the column family may include millions of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: use CQL, it will make more sense. http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/ddl/table

Longer answer: setting Thrift column_metadata will drop or create indexes as needed to make Cassandra's internal schema match what you told it to update to.  It will not let you change a column type to something incompatible, but you can "fool" it by removing the definition and re-adding it.

NB: if you are changing your schema daily you are doing it wrong, whether you are using CQL or Thrift.

Comment: Yes, I exaggerated with "daily" updates of the schema.  Basically I am writing a script that produces a cli update command, which sys admins may run occasionally, and am wondering whether I need to worry about making my script aware of existing columns to only create new ones.

Comment: Not with this approach, you don't.